# Combine overlaying with underline command

Tags: beamer, overlays

I would like a word to be only underlined from the second slide onwards, but "\underline<2->{...}" doesn't get recognized unfortunately. Does anybody know an alternative? Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a custom, overlay aware macro for underlining:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{ulem}

\newcommand<>{\myunderline}[1]{\alt#2{\underline{#1}}{#1}}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
    \myunderline<2>{test}
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, works great!

Comment: @nkor87 You're welcome!

Comment: In case anyone wants to learn more about how the overlay is "passed on" to `alt`, see Section 9.6 (Advanced Overlay Specifications) of the Beamer User Guide: https://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf 
 @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I'm trying to keep my word of studying it (little by little) :)

Comment: @scottkosty Interesting reading material, isn't it? :)

Comment: Yes, It sure is!